# Why am I getting 403 status code in Java after a while?

Tags: java, http, web-scraping, http-headers, http-status-code-403

When I try to check status codes within sites I face off 403 response code after a while. First when I run the code every sites send back datas but after my code repeat itself with Timer I see one webpage returns 403 response code. Here is my code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void checkSites() {
        Timer ifSee403 = new Timer();

        try {
            File links = new File("./linkler.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(links);
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                list.add(scan.nextLine());
            }
            File linkStatus = new File("LinkStatus.txt");
            if(!linkStatus.exists()){
                linkStatus.createNewFile();
            }else{
                System.out.println("File already exists");
            }
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(linkStatus));
            for(String link : list) {
                try {
                    if(!link.startsWith("http")) {
                        link = "http://"+link;
                    }
                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
                    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    http.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                    http.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    http.setReadTimeout(8000);

                    int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
                    if (statusCode == 200) {
                        ifSee403.wait(5000);
                        System.out.println("Hello, here we go again");
                    }
                    http.disconnect();
                    System.out.println(link + " " + statusCode);
                    writer.write(link + " " + statusCode);
                    writer.newLine();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    writer.write(link + " " + e.getMessage());
                    writer.newLine();

                    System.out.println(link + " " +e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            try {
                writer.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println("Finished.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        Timer myTimer = new Timer();

        TimerTask sendingRequest = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                checkSites();
            }
        };
        myTimer.schedule(sendingRequest,0,150000);

    }
}
```

How can I solve this? Thanks

Edited comment:

1. I've added http.disconnect(); for closing connection after checked status codes.
2. Also I've added

   ```
   if(statusCode == 200) {
   ifSee403.wait(5000);
   System.out.println("Test message);
   ```

   }

But it didn't work. Compiler returned current thread is not owner error. I need to fix this and change 200 with 403 and say ifSee403.wait(5000) and try it again the status code.

Comment: probably server is protected against to many request from the same ip. I guess. 403 is forbidden content

Comment: **LOOK:** Beating this type off security - and I have looked into this before, but never bothered to take it to completion - would involve using things like `"The Onion Router"` (***Tor Network***) - which means use a ***Proxy HTTP Server*** so your web-sites are receiving a request from a different **IP Address** on each request.  This is easy in Java, and there are ***many Stack Overflow Answers*** about using `Proxy Servers` in Java.  ***However,*** the last time I tried - I found a company / site called `Illuminati.io` and they wanted all kinds of credit card information for IP Addresses..

Comment: If this sort of thing ***is that important to you*** you are going to have to ***pay money*** for proxy `IP Address` that some company will allow you to use to make **HTTP Requests** (anonymously).  After you have these addresses, just look up any answer about using a `proxy`.  It is not very fun, and really annoying to even think about shelling out money and your credit-card information to a bunch of fly-by-night no-name web-sites...  Try `illuminati.io` if you need to beat `HTTP 403`...  But I'm not going to help you with that - _anymore than to give you the name of the web-site..._

Answer (score 1):

One "alternative" - by the way - to IP / Spoofing / Anonymizing would be to (instead) try "obeying" what the security-code is expecting you to do.  If you are going to write a "scraper", and are aware there is a "bot detection" that doesn't like you debugging your code while you visit the site ***over and over and over*** - you should try using the **HTML Download** which I posted as an answer to the last question you asked.

If you ***download the HTML and save it*** (save it to a file - once an hour), and then write you **HTML Parsing / Monitoring Code** using the HTML contents of the file you have saved, you will (likely) be abiding by the security-requirements of the web-site ***and still be able to check availability***.

If you wish to continue to use **JSoup**, that A.P.I. has an option for receiving HTML ***as a String***.  So if you use the HTML Scrape Code I posted, and then write that `HTML String` to disk, you can feed that to **JSoup** as often as you like without causing the **Bot Detection Security Checks** to go off.

If you play by their rules once in a while, you can write your tester without much hassle.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

...

// This line asks the "url" that you are trying to connect with for
// an instance of HttpURLConnection.  These two classes (URL and HttpURLConnection)
// are in the standard JDK Package java.net.*

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Tells the connection to use "GET" ... and to "pretend" that you are
// using a "Chrome" web-browser.  Note, the User-Agent sometimes means 
// something to the web-server, and sometimes is fully ignored.

con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Chrome/61.0.3163.100");

// The classes InputStream, InputStreamReader, and BufferedReader
// are all JDK 1.0 package java.io.* classes.

InputStream      is = con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader   br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuffer     sb = new StringBuffer();
String           s;

// This reads each line from the web-server.
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) sb.append(s + "\n");

// This writes the results from the web-server to a file
// It is using classes java.io.File and java.io.FileWriter

File outF = new File("SavedSite.html");
outF.createNewFile();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outF);
fw.write(sb.toString());
fw.close();
```

Again, this code is very basic stuff that doesn't use any special ***JAR Library Code*** at all.  The next method uses the **JSoup** library (which you have explicitly requested - even though I don't use it... It is just fine!)  ... This is the method "parse" which will parse the `String` you have just saved.  You may load this `HTML String` from disk, and send it to **JSoup** using:

> Method Documentation: [`org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse​(File in, String charsetName, String baseUri)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse(java.io.File,java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

If you wish to invoke **JSoup** just pass it a `java.io.File` instance using the following:

```
File f = new File("SavedSite.html");
Document d = Jsoup.parse(f, "UTF-8", url.toString());
```

I do not think you need timers at all...

**AGAIN:** If you are making lots of calls to the server.  The purpose of this answer is to show you how to save the response of the server to a file on disk, ***so you don't have to make lots of calls - JUST ONE!***  If you restrict your calls to the server to once per hour, then you will (likely, but not a guarantee) avoid getting a `403 Forbidden` Bot Detection Problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to write all code for a hour. I'm quite beginner, your answer looks like the correct one, probably. Can you write all code to me? Even includes timer and other stuff that you explained about it. After writing code, can you explain step by step? You can use comment lines within code block. Think about you are explaining to very first beginner, otherwise I still couldn't understand it. You can save my life if you teached me well. Thank you anyway my friend.

Comment: I added code comments.  I did not include ***'timers'*** because the point is that you will only call this method once per hour.  I usually use a different **HTML Scrape** package than **JSoup** - but I do not think you should need them, unless **JSoup** has some kind of earlier timeout mechanism.

Comment: If site turns HTML code that doesn't mean site is up. So the code which I posted look better. I've updated my question with the latest code situation I have. I need to say to compiler **IF THE STATUS CODE 403, WAIT AND TRY AGAIN 5 SECONDS LATER or CONTINUE TO RUN CODE THEN CHECK STATUS CODE OF SITE  WHICH HAS ALREADY TURNED 403, AFTER NEXT SITE.** Can you help me for this? I mean if I say
if(statuscode = 200) {  // I assigned 200 not 403 because for test
       myTimer.wait(5000);
       System.out.println("Test message");
}
When I write this compiler says, current thread is not owner

Comment: ***OK !!! That's the whole point !!!*** (This has happened to me many times)...  If the web-server is telling you "403" because it is receiving multiple requests ***from the same IP Address*** - there is nothing you can do at all except: WAIT **OR** try an IP Proxy...   If you keep bothering them over and over their "Ban" will likely increase - ***that is bot detection***  (It has happened to me, too)  You have to wait till tomorrow and try again!  Here is  **my main point:** If you download the HTML, and play with it "offline" _at the very least you can get some work done_

Comment: OK "!!!" Forget the 403, focus only this part: ***WHEN COMPILER GETS 403 CODE, I WANT TO SAY WAIT 5 SECONDS AND TRY TO GET STATUS CODE AGAIN*** just and _only_ that is my problem. Check my edited post please

Comment: You can't do that...  You have to wait (in my experience) 24 hours.  Maybe a week. (not 5 seconds).

Comment: If you buy an "IP Address Proxy" (like `Illuminati.io`) and pay them money using a credit-card, you can use lots of **IP Addresses** - and it won't block you.  But you have to learn the Proxy Server / Anonymiser Code...  (It's similar to a VPN that hides your IP Address).  I don't do that stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223587/discussion-between-y2020-09-and-arthurmorgan).